# How to list all users and their permissions from projects in Python-Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I can get users and their permissions from a group:

```
gl = gitlab.Gitlab("https://gitlab.etc.org/", private_token='private_token', ssl_verify=False)

group = gl.groups.get(xxx)

member = group.members.all(all=True)

for mem in member:
    if mem.access_level == 50: # only owners
        print (f'Owners from repository/project : {mem.name}')
```

I can list the projects from a group using:

`projects = group.projects.list(all=True)`

But how do I get the project's users?

`users = projects.users.list()` # this command doesn't work

Also tried fetching users, and listing what projects they are member of but this functionality seems to work only for admins?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Python-GitLab library, but I see that you have `group.members.all` and if it's using GitLab convention/naming then you would need to loop through each project, then list the members, so for the first project in the list `p=group.projects.first` then `p.members.all`

Comment: Thanks Arty-chan, I did try that but it didn't quite work. I think the problem is that the API exists but it doesn't work,

Comment: you may need to file an issue specifically for the Python-GitLab project then. I know for a fact that the project members API itself works

Comment: Is there a typing error? "projects.users.list()" should be "project.users.list()". You should iterate over your projects -> for p in projects: users = p.users.list()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit too late now - but the code above worked. That was a permission problem.